# When unit testing mjs files, is there a way to mutate an imported function without using jest.mock?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Using module mocks in Jest has been done since the dawn of time, however as we move into the world of mjs it's impossible to intercept calls to `require` at runtime to enable this pattern.

```
jest.mock('./filename')
```

While I generally try my best to parameterize my dependencies, there are some cases where it's not possible (such as third party dependencies) or it's inconvenient and I need to explicitly mock out a single or multiple properties in a module.

I have tried various ways to reassign a property:

```
// foo.mjs
export function foo() {
  console.log('foo')
}
```

**Simple reassignment - fails**

```
import { foo } from './foo.mjs'
import * as fooModule from './foo.mjs'

fooModule.foo = function() { 
  console.log('bar')
}

console.log(foo())
```

**Object.defineProperty - fails**

```
import { foo } from './foo.mjs'
import * as fooModule from './foo.mjs'

Object.defineProperty(fooModule, 'foo', { value: function() { 
  console.log('bar')
}})

console.log(foo())
```

**Object.assign - fails**

```
import { foo } from './foo.mjs'
import * as fooModule from './foo.mjs'

Object.assign(fooModule, {
  foo: function() { 
    console.log('bar')
  }
})

console.log(foo())
```

All of these attempts fail with

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'foo' of object '[object Module]'
```

In new Node with modules, is there an expected way to monkey patch modules or parts of a module such that all subsequent imports of that module receive that patch?

Comment: You need to turn on experimental ES modules support with Jest: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

Comment: One way doing that is by updating your test script to this: `"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"`